# linking to a PDF file using rails and carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, carrierwave

I am trying to have a link to a pdf file on a website.  When someone clicks on the link, it should open the pdf file up in a new browser window.

I have the following code in the view:

```
<% @filtered_portfolio_files.each do |the_file| %>
    <li>
        <% if the_file.is_picture? %>
            <%= image_tag(the_file.port_file.picture) %> 
        <% else %> 
            <%= link_to image_tag('/assets/pdf_image.png'), the_file, target: '_blank' %> 
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

This should show the image if the file is an image or a dummy picture of the Adobe PDF logo that links to the pdf file if the file is a PDF.

Right now this loop goes through two files.  The first is an image and the 2nd is a PDF.  It correctly shows the first image and the 2nd correctly shows an image of the PDF logo, but when clicked on it brings me to a page that says

```
No route matches [GET] "/portfolio_files/4"
```

I have also tried in the view:

```
<% @filtered_portfolio_files.each do |the_file| %>
    <li>
        <% if the_file.is_picture? %>
            <%= image_tag(the_file.port_file.picture) %> 
        <% else %> 
            <%= link_to image_tag('/assets/pdf_image.png'), the_file.port_file, target: '_blank' %> 
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

but that stops the page from loading and returns the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for PortfoliofileUploader:Class
```

How do I get the PDF link to correctly link to correctly link to the pdf file?

Comment: can you try replacing `<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/pdf_image.png'), the_file, target: '_blank' %>`  with `<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/pdf_image.png'), asset_path(the_file), target: '_blank' %> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/pdf_image.png'), the_file.port_file.url, target: '_blank' %>
```

Add a `.url` on the end.